# Terminology/Reference: Stochatic domination with "slack"

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, terminology

I'm looking for the name of the following (well-known?) property, or usage of it:
Let $X,Y$ be random variables (or distributions) over $\mathbb{R}$.
What is the name of following "dominance with slack $L$":
$$
\Pr[X > c] \leq L \cdot \Pr[Y > c]
$$

Comment: what you mean by "What's the name of $\dots$"? It is indeed stochastic domination with slack variable $L$

Comment: Look like I guessed right. Can you post a reference (as an answer)? My search-fu wasn't good enough...